# Facebook timeline "pinned" post how to get via graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql, facebook-timeline

The graph or FQL (which has the same data) do not list the relevant property in any of the tables that I've checked.

The order of posts in the "stream" does not change with items being **pinned**.

To clarify just in case, I am asking about the new timeline feature where you can click "edit" on a post and then select **"Pin to top"**. 
I have to be able to find the **pinned** post via API or FQL or RSS or any other reasonably reliable way, and I don't need to make a post pinned - just to query for it.

Thank you.

TJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no current way to get this information.  You should put in a bug with Facebook at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs.

I looked at both beta docs as well as the public documentation too.

http://developers.beta.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/
and
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

It's possible that the new postings are a new "type", but here's the list of current stream types.

> The type of this story. Possible values are:
>
> ```
> 11 - Group created
> 12 - Event created
> 46 - Status update
> 56 - Post on wall from another user
> 66 - Note created
> 80 - Link posted
> 128 - Video posted
> 247 - Photos posted
> 237 - App story
> 272 - App story
> ```

Comment: thank you, here is the bug url for when someone else stumbles in here :  http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/287559117982591

Comment: Thanks for adding a bug.  You can now close this question.  Thanks  :)

Comment: The bug does not exist in developers.facebook.com/bugs/ anymore, what are the news?